# Javascript Math.pow() returning Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to  figure out why this:

```
Populations[0] = Math.round(Math.pow((Populations[0] * Math.E), (popGrowth * 5)));
Populations[1] = Math.round(Math.pow((Populations[1] * Math.E), (popGrowth * 5)));
Populations[2] = Math.round(Math.pow((Populations[2] * Math.E), (popGrowth * 5)));
```

returns this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/steventang166/rrsjc79q/72/

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.getElementById("buttonEndTurn").addEventListener('click', endTurn());
});
var Populations = [100, 100, 100];
var popGrowth = [0.1797];
var resourceGold = [1000, 1000, 1000];
var resourceWood = [500, 500, 500];
var minerPercent1 = 0.5;
var minerPercent2 = 0.75;
var minerPercent3 = 0.1;
var Miners = [0, 0, 0];
var Loggers = [0, 0, 0];
var endTurn = function (Populations,popGrowth,resourceGold,resourceWood,minerPercent1,minerPercent2,minerPercent3,Minners,Loggers) {
    popGrowth += Math.random;

    Populations[0] = Math.round(Math.pow((Populations[0] * Math.E), (popGrowth * 5)));
    Populations[1] = Math.round(Math.pow((Populations[1] * Math.E), (popGrowth * 5)));
    Populations[2] = Math.round(Math.pow((Populations[2] * Math.E), (popGrowth * 5)));
        
 for (var m = 0; m < 3;m++) {console.log(Populations[m])};
    
    Miners = [Math.round(Populations[0] * minerPercent1),
    Math.round(Populations[1] * minerPercent2),
    Math.round(Populations[2] * minerPercent3)];

    Loggers = [Populations[0] - Miners[0],
    Populations[1] - Miners[1],
    Populations[2] - Miners[2]];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        console.log(Miners[i]);
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        console.log(Loggers[j]);
    }

    resourceGold[0] += Miners[0] * 100;
    resourceGold[1] += Miners[1] * 100;
    resourceGold[2] += Miners[2] * 100;

    resourceWood[0] += Loggers[0] * 100;
    resourceWood[1] += Loggers[1] * 100;
    resourceWood[2] += Loggers[2] * 100;

    for (var k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        console.log(resourceGold[k]);
    }

    for (var l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
        console.log(resourceWood[l]);
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttonEndTurn">End Turn</button>
<canvas id="hexCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="width:800px;height:600px" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is [`function` scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript). Hence, as soon as you declare a variable in a function, it *hides* variables with the same name from the global scope.

In your case, you have *hidden* the variable `Populations` by making it an argument to the function `endTurn`:

```
var endTurn = function (Populations,popGrowth,resourceGold,resourceWood,minerPercent1,minerPercent2,minerPercent3,Minners,Loggers) {
```

Hence, `Populations` is `undefined` inside the function instead of holding the value it should from the global scope, which should be:

```
var Populations = [100, 100, 100];
```

To fix the *error*, simply remove the argument `Populations` from the list of arguments to `endTurn` function.

Additionally, you are *calling* the function `endTurn` while trying to bind it to the `click` event. You probably meant to write:

```
document.getElementById("buttonEndTurn").addEventListener('click', endTurn); // <-- without the brackets
```

---

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nz3qn1dq/1/

There were a few more tweaks which were needed to get the function to work as you probably intended:

```
var popGrowth = 0.1797; // <-- Changed from a 1d array to just a number

// ...

popGrowth += Math.random(); // <-- Invoking the Math.random function with brackets.
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that `Populations` itself is undefined.  You can't index `undefined` it with `[0]`

---

From looking at your jsfiddle, You might think that it would be defined because of this:

```
var Populations = [100, 100, 100];
```

but that array is being hidden by a parameter in your function

```
var endTurn = function (Populations,popGrowth,resourceGold,resourceWood,minerPercent1,minerPercent2,minerPercent3,Minners,Loggers) {
```

but you're not passing any parameters into that function, therefore, all the parameters in your function's signature will default to `undefined`.

```
document.getElementById("buttonEndTurn").addEventListener('click', endTurn());
```

Answer (score 1):

You define your function like this:

```
var endTurn = function (Populations,popGrowth,resourceGold,resourceWood,minerPercent1,minerPercent2,minerPercent3,Minners,Loggers) {
```

This creates local variables with all those variable names, which overshadow the variables in your main closure.

Then you attach the listener like this, which calls the function immediately instead of assigning the function to the button:

```
.addEventListener('click', endTurn())
```

---

What you want to do instead is define it like this, so it pulls the variables in from the outer closure:

```
var endTurn = function () {
```

And then attach the event listener using the function reference like this:

```
.addEventListener('click', endTurn)
```

Comment: @StevenTang To answer your question, a few more errors I'm seeing in your code: (1) `Math.random` should be `Math.random()`, which is probably contributing to the NaN values. (2) On line 25 you have a stray closing square bracket. There are probably a few more small errors in your code - I would recommend putting in a lot more `console.log` statements in your code to help debug it (or look into using the Chrome debugger if you're up for it!) and take it from the top, squelching each of the irregularities you find. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete all your parameters. (Or you could pass in the outer variables as arguments)

Or, you can pass all your variables into your function as the parameters when you call it. The function call would look like this:

```
endTurn(Populations, popGrowth, resourceGold, resourceWood, 
minerPercent1, minerPercent2, minerPercent3, Minners, Loggers);
```

Inside the function, parameters are similar to local variables, so inside the function, the interpreter thinks "Populations" refers to an undefined parameter. When we call our function, we can pass in exterior variables and functions and refer to them by their local names within the function. Or, if we don't redeclare the same variable/function names, we can just refer to the outer variables inside our function.

I prefer to keep as many local variables scoped within the function that uses them, whenever I can. This makes it easier for me to traverse my code and keeps my functions/variables from conflicting with one another.

Comment: Dear Shain, welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow answers are expected to provide substantial solutions to the problem that not only explain what to change, but also illustrate why the changes need to be made, so that the original poster might learn from their mistakes. For more details, please see [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Comment: I feel like I answered it pretty well... let me know what's particularly wrong with my post.

Comment: At the time I posted my comment, your answer was a single short sentence. It seems like you've since edited your answer to be much more substantial. Thank you for the answer and sorry for any inconvenience!